# Why would a 4 member board be required to be reduced to 3 members?

Tags: hoa

Florida HOA CAM writes:

> Per Board Member request, Since the Board has not been able to fill
>   the vacant 5th seat on the Board, the Board will need to be decreased
>   to 3 Members.  With this said, XXX or YY will need to step down as a
>   Board Member as to not have control of the Board as part of the
>   Developers per previously received legal opinion.  We will need to
>   receive a resignation.

What reason is there to **compel or require** a reduction in board members?  There has not been a meeting called so there has not been an attempt to fill the seat.

Comment: It would be difficult to know without reading the mentioned legal opinion, but usually these boards have odd members so that they can't have a split vote.

Comment: Board member #5 quit.  This particular legal opinion is from a lawyer not a judge.

Comment: There are currently four members, but the opinion says one of two members need to leave... is that because the two are developers, and there's a rule saying developers need to be a minority?  My guess is there's some rule about board composition that's being triggered.

Comment: The quoted section is not an opinion but a claim from a non-lawyer / non-judge.   kbelder question is on track, however, I am unable to find anything in the statues that compel.